# Define possible values for a property in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder, mxml

In Flex, is it possible to include some kind of MetaData to a property, to be able to list all possible values that a property can use? I want to be able to list the values when calling the property from MXML, as in the case of for example the property *enabled* or *visible*, where the user gets a list of "true/false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Inspectable](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#159728) metadata tag.  In your case you'll want to explicitly use the *enumeration* attribute.

```
[Inspectable( enumeration="one,two,three" )]
public var myProp:String;
```